# Chrome on Android: createObjectURL containing image blob captured from camera is broken

Tags: android, html, google-chrome

This worked for me before, but is now broken on a few (but not all) Android devices using Chrome (v38 as well as Canary/Beta are broken).

If the input is set to capture from camera, the blob returned is invalid (a broken image appears). If I unset that attribute and choose from gallery instead, the image loads fine. This works on my phone, but not on a few tablets.

Does anyone know if anything has changed in Chrome? Unfortunately, I am not sure if the chrome on the broken devices has been updated.

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="edit_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">    
<input {$readonly} id="input" type="file"  accept="image/*" capture="camera" />
<div class='fileinput-preview thumbnail' data-trigger="fileinput" style="min-height: 267px; width: 200px; border: 1px solid black;" id="photo_front"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#input").change(function() {
    var file = this.files[0];
    var imgURL = URL.createObjectURL(file), img = document.createElement('img');
    img.onload = function() { URL.revokeObjectURL(imgURL); };
    img.src = imgURL;        
    img.width = 200;
    $("#photo_front").html('');
    $("#photo_front").append(img);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yL3e14Lj/6/

Answer (score -2):

I posted chrome issue but somehow its still unconfirmed and moved to Restricted (No idea what that means).. Try posting on chromium issue the more info they have the sonner fix will be.

I tested this on some devices. 
Works :
- 4.3.1 (Galaxy S I9000 - Rooted)
- 4.4.4 (Nexus 7)
- 4.4.3 (HTC One M8)

Not working :
- 4.2.2 (Samsung Tab 3 10.1) - Not crashing : just not showing image 
- 4.0.4 (Samsung Tab 1 10.1) - Crashes with "aw snap"

looks like its bound to android version